# Is it possible to write an iPhone app that emulates a usb keyboard?

Tags: ios

I do a lot of Raspberry Pi projects and I often get into a situation where I’ve just uploaded a new OS to an SD card and want to start a project but I have no keyboard and/or monitor handy. I usually use VNC to control my Pis from my phone or computer but you need a keyboard and monitor to set up VNC server. I realize it would be impossible to send monitor data over usb to an iPhone but would it be possible to create an iPhone app that emulates a normal usb keyboard?

In the app’s simplest form, the user would be able to plug in a normal usb cable to their iPhone and computer, open the app (just a keyboard) and be able to send keystrokes to the computer.

Comment: I think this needs some hardware changes as well. Seems impossible by app only.

Comment: No. This is not possible

Comment: Do you know why it’s not possible? Some ios apps have access to the usb port in certain situations. Why should this situation be restricted?

Answer (score 0):

If you do a lot of raspberry projects, maybe you have a spare pi0 lying around? In that case you'd need about half of https://github.com/mikerr/pihidproxy, plus an ssh app on the iphone.